# Kingoffice availability for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, docking

Is there a free version of Kingoffice for Ubuntu 12.04?

If not, what are existing alternatives ?

Answer (score 1):

Kingoffice is free as in free beer but not free as in freedom. So you don't have to spend money to install it but cannot modify or even study its source code, even if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is a version that works on Ubuntu 12.04.

But, I may suggest using Libre Office as it is free and already included into Ubuntu.